# Evaluate $\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{(z+1)(z-1)}$

Tags: complex-analysis

> $$\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{(z+1)(z-1)}dz$$
>
> $\gamma(t)=it, -1\leq t\leq 1$

$$\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{(z+1)(-1)}dz=\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{(z^2-1)}dz=\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{i}{((ti)^2-1)}dt=-i\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{dt}{t^2+1}=-i\arctan(t)|_{-1}^{1}=-i(\arctan(1)-\arctan(-1))=-i\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Is there another way to solve it? can we use the fact the on the curve $z=yi$? or can we use Cauchy integral formula?

Comment: The Cauchy formula can't be used (I think) because we need a circle - the curve in question is a line.