# If $\gamma$ is the circle $|z|=\frac{1}{2}$, then $\int_\gamma \frac{dz}{(z-1)(z+1)}$?

Tags: integration, contour-integration

Regarding the question posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2394809/evaluate-int-gamma-frac1z1z-1) on MathStackExchange, what is the value of the integral if $\gamma$ is the circle $|z|=\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's equal to zero directly from the Cauchy's theorem because the function $\frac{1}{z^2-1}$ is holomorphic inside the circle.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.

Comment: @MartinR 1. I don't think the question violates any of the site policies. It may violate rules meant as *advices* for writing a good question, but first of all, they are not mandatory, and second of all, these advices are not always helpful or applicable. 2. As a person with no practice using the search engine, it takes me much less time to simply answer the question than look for duplicates. Particularly in this case I have no clue how searching for a duplicate would look like (what am I supposed to input - the function formula?), so I don't think it would be worth its time (my time).